# Order by index usage

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sugarcrm

I am researching a peculiar order by issue I have encountered with SugarCRM which I think the following test case describes:

- Given the following two tables:

  ```
    CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name char(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

  CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name char(20),
   name2 varchar(10),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
  ```
- insert random data into table test1:

  ```
   delimiter $$  
   create procedure randomizer()
   begin
   declare i int Default 0 ;
   declare random char(20) ;
   declare random2 char(10) ;
   myloop: loop
   set random=conv(floor(rand() * 99999999999999), 20, 36) ;
   insert into test1 (id, name) VALUES (i+1,random) ;
   set i=i+1;
   if i=1000 then
    leave myloop;
  ```

  end if;
       end loop myloop;
       end $$
       delimiter ;
- insert random data into table test2:

  ```
   delimiter $$  
   create procedure randomizer()
   begin
   declare i int Default 0 ;
   declare random char(20) ;
   declare random2 char(10) ;
   myloop: loop
   set random=conv(floor(rand() * 99999999999999), 20, 36) ;
   set random2=conv(floor(rand() * 999999), 10, 36) ;
   insert into test2 (id, name, name2) VALUES (i+1,random, random2) ;
   set i=i+1;
   if i=1000 then
   leave myloop;
  ```

  end if;
       end loop myloop;
       end $$
       delimiter ;
- Add secondary indexes:

  ```
       alter table test1 add index(name);

       alter table test2 add index(name);
  ```
- Execute a QEP using a table join with an order by on the first table in the join:

  ```
  explain select test1.name, test2.name from test1 left join test2 on test1.id=test2.id order by test1.name

  +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
  | id | select_type | table |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |      ref      | rows |    Extra    |
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | test1 | index  | NULL          | name    |      21 | NULL          |  981 | Using index |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | test2 | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | test.test1.id |    1 |             |
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
  ```
- And again but order by on the second table in the join:

  ```
  explain select test1.name, test2.name from test1 left join test2 on test1.id=test2.id order by test2.name

  +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
  | id | select_type | table |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |      ref      | rows |                    Extra                     |
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | test1 | index  | NULL          | name    |      21 | NULL          |  981 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | test2 | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | test.test1.id |    1 |                                              |
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
  ```

I do not understand why query 2 uses the filesort while query 1 is able to use the index. Is it possible I am encountering the following limitation described in this document?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

"You are joining many tables, and the columns in the ORDER BY are not all from the first nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows. (This is the first table in the EXPLAIN output that does not have a const join type.)"

Comment: Could you please format this correctly perhaps using preformatted text tags? It's very hard to read the SQL output.

Comment: hmm, trying to, added blockquotes but it is still messsing up the formatting, but be some strange chars there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly identified why your second query isn't using the index.

Since you've doing a `LEFT JOIN` from `test1` to `test2`, `test1` is the first *nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows*, so the columns from `test2` can't be sorted using an index.

I don't think there's a way for your query to keep the same functionally but use the index for `test2`... but if you were to change the join type from `left join` to `inner join`, it should then make use of the index.